# `systemctl reload sendmail` throws `Job type not applicable"

Tags: systemd, sendmail

When I try to use `systemctl` to reload the `sendmail` configuration I get an error. Is this a bug or should I just avoid trying to use `systemctl` with `sendmail`?

What is the recommended way to teach `systemctl` to allow reload for the `sendmail.service`?

Please no religious debates on systemd.

Output of `systemctl reload sendmail`:

```
Failed to reload sendmail.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit sendmail.service.
See system logs and 'systemctl status sendmail.service' for details.
```

And `systemctl status sendmail.service`:

```
● sendmail.service - LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sendmail; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-09-20 15:13:35 CDT; 7h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1476 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sendmail start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 3.2M
      CPU: 805ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/sendmail.service
           └─1621 sendmail: MTA: accepting connections

Sep 20 15:48:45 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2407]: u8KKmjv5002407: SYSERR(root): btree map "drac": missing map file /var/lib/drac/drac.db: No such file or directory
Sep 20 15:48:45 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2407]: u8KKmjv5002407: ruleset=check_rcpt, arg1=<Postmaster@mayrich.net>, relay=mx.cableone.net [64.8.70.47], reject=550 5.7.1 <Postmaster@mayrich.net>... Relaying denied
Sep 20 15:48:50 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2407]: u8KKmjv5002407: from=<>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mx.cableone.net [64.8.70.47]
Sep 20 15:53:57 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2433]: u8KKrvRq002433: SYSERR(root): btree map "drac": missing map file /var/lib/drac/drac.db: No such file or directory
Sep 20 15:53:57 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2433]: u8KKrvRq002433: ruleset=check_rcpt, arg1=<Postmaster@mayrich.net>, relay=mx.cableone.net [64.8.70.47], reject=550 5.7.1 <Postmaster@mayrich.net>... Relaying denied
Sep 20 15:54:02 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2433]: u8KKrvRq002433: from=<>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mx.cableone.net [64.8.70.47]
Sep 20 16:03:45 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2503]: u8KL3je5002503: SYSERR(root): btree map "drac": missing map file /var/lib/drac/drac.db: No such file or directory
Sep 20 16:03:45 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2503]: u8KL3je5002503: ruleset=check_rcpt, arg1=<Postmaster@mayrich.net>, relay=mx.cableone.net [64.8.70.47], reject=550 5.7.1 <Postmaster@mayrich.net>... Relaying denied
Sep 20 16:03:50 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[2503]: u8KL3je5002503: from=<>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mx.cableone.net [64.8.70.47]
Sep 20 20:02:53 yin.bl-3.com sm-mta[4051]: ruleset=check_relay, arg1=[185.40.4.126], arg2=127.0.0.3, relay=m126.mediumthings.net [185.40.4.126] (may be forged), reject=553 5.3.0 Message From 185.40.4.126 rejected -see http://spamhau
~
```

Comment: What is reported by `systemctl status sendmail.service`?

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: [Edit] your question and put the result of running that command into it.

Comment: My question is what is the preferred way to fix this issue. While it is interesting how it became broken. It is also informative that Debian and therefore Ubuntu have not worked to fix this. I have not seen information on the preferred way to fix this besides you will have to write your own systemd file. <sarcasm>Really? I would have never thought of that on my own.</sarcasm> I am unfamiliar with the structure of the systemd files so pointers to a style guide for them would be useful. Or if someone has already come up with a fixed version that would be useful.

Comment: One additional question, if I enhance the systemd configuration file to handle the reload function, who should I submit it to? Ubuntu, Debian, or sendmail themselves? All of them?

Comment: Well I'm learning that the automatically generated systemd script for sendmail is horse poo. It doesn't handle stop or restart either. Is there a better prototype rc file to use for systemd to work from? How about just having it run the init.d file with the argument?

Answer (score 3):

That error typically means that the client program (in this case `sendmail`) doesn't expose a reload method to `systemctl` to use. This is the fault of the developers/maintainers, and not `systemctl`. (Perhaps `sendmail` can't just plain reload the configs?)

I would recommend just plain restarting `sendmail` whenever you need to reload the configuration:

```
sudo systemctl restart sendmail
```

This will kill `sendmail` and then start it up again as a fresh daemon instance. As a result, any new config changes will take effect, but you may lose temporary data.

Answer (score 1):

The status output has told you everything.

```
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

This is the manual page describing the special way in which your `sendmail.service` unit has been created.

```
sendmail.service - LSB: powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Transport Agent
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sendmail; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
```

These tells you that the van Smoorenburg `rc` script named `/etc/init.d/sendmail` was used to auto-generate a `sendmail.service` unit, and that it was recognized as having a set of LSB directives (rather than the alternative).

Service units auto-generated from van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts do not support reloading, except where the generator detects a very specific pattern string in the `rc` script.  It didn't with yours, and has no idea how to issue a reload, or that reload is even meaningful for the service at all.  Your old van Smoorenburg `rc` script simply doesn't provide the information for the service unit generator.

Neither Debian nor Ubuntu supply systemd service units for Sendmail.  You'll have to write some if you want them; or find them already written somewhere.

It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `systemctl daemon-reload`
It should works